# Pandas dataframe : Pipe separated values in a cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
from      to         cc      extra columns
-------------------------------------------
1          2          3           sth
1|1        4                      sth
3          1|2       4|5          sth
```

I want a new dataframe that creates a new row for every pipe separated value like this:

```
from       to        cc       extra columns
--------------------------------------------
1           2         3          sth
1           4                    sth
1           4                    sth
3           1         4          sth
3           2         4          sth
3           1         5          sth
3           2         5          sth
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, what errors are you getting? You need to show some effort to solve the question. Show us some code, and maybe then you will get the help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `numpy`

- `split` column by column.
- `concatenate` target column while `repeat` on the rest of the array

---

```
def explode(v, i, sep='|'):
    v = v.astype(str)
    n, m = v.shape
    a = v[:, i]
    bslc = np.r_[0:i, i+1:m]
    asrt = np.append(i, bslc).argsort()
    b = v[:, bslc]
    a = np.core.defchararray.split(a, sep)
    A = np.concatenate(a)[:, None]
    counts = [len(x) for x in a.tolist()]
    rpt = np.arange(n).repeat(counts)
    return np.concatenate([A, b[rpt]], axis=1)[:, asrt]

pd.DataFrame(
    explode(explode(explode(df.values, 0), 1), 2),
    columns=df.columns
)

  from to cc extra_columns
0    1  2  3           sth
1    1  4              sth
2    1  4              sth
3    3  1  4           sth
4    3  1  5           sth
5    3  2  4           sth
6    3  2  5           sth
```

---

***time test***
*given data*
**10 X faster**
[image]

*given data repeated 1000 times*
**100 X faster**
[image]

Comment: OMG!! This is SO much faster! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @Gingerbread I saw you marked mine as the answer, then gave it back to scomes.  I'm not concerned about the rep or the having the answer.  I **am** concerned that you tried it and it came back incorrect.  Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Yes, I did do that. And I added my previous comment only after trying out your solution. Both the solutions worked for me. I thought I would give him credit since he got the answer first. I wish we could accept as many answers on SO as possible! But again, I think yours deserves much more than just an accept of the solution! Salute!!

Answer (score 2):

A not elegant but working solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', index_col=None)

all_rows = []
for _, r in df.iterrows():

    froms = str(r['from']).split('|')
    to = str(r['to']).split('|')
    ccs = str(r['cc']).split('|')

    rows = [[f, t, cc] + list(r[df.columns[3:]]) for f, t, cc in itertools.product(froms, to, ccs)]
    all_rows += rows

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows, columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to move outside of pandas to do the list manipulation, then port the new data back into a pandas dataframe.  Here we use `product` from itertools to create all of the combinations after splitting each row into a bunch of lists.

Note that I use letters instead of number for my data.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame([['a',  'b', 'c', 'xtra'],
                   ['a|a','d',  '', 'xtra'],
                   ['c',  'a|b','d|e','xtra']],
                   columns=['From','To','CC','extra_cols'])

split_data = []
for row in df.values.tolist():
    split_data.extend(list(product(*[item.split('|') for item in row])))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(split_data, columns=['From','To','CC','extra_cols'])

> new_df
#   From To CC extra_cols
# 0    a  b  c       xtra
# 1    a  d          xtra
# 2    a  d          xtra
# 3    c  a  d       xtra
# 4    c  a  e       xtra
# 5    c  b  d       xtra
# 6    c  b  e       xtra
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply. I got the following error: "AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'split'".

Comment: You data is probably not all stored as text.